# Hide price for not login user break my theme

Tags: php, customer, phtml

I purchased a theme that has prices hidden I followed a tutorial 
that demonstrated how to hide prices  so I did that and removed the all of

```
<?php
   if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
       echo '<span class="login_for_price"><strong>Login to See Price</strong></span><br>';
       return;
   }
?>
```

from the files, I was still unable to view the the prices only when logged in i  used the debug tool to locate what phtml file was calling the prices

[image]

when logged in and i tried to remove the

```
   <?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){ ?>
```

file but i broke my theme here is picture of the file

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you have an error in your code, in your line **3** replace :

```
`<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){ ?>`
```

with

```
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
```

To check if the customer is logged you do that:

```
<?php if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
   //some code exemple: show this text just for logged users
<?php endif; ?>
```

To check if the is not logged you do this:

```
<?php if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
   //some code exemple: show this text just for the not logged users
<?php endif; ?>
```

To display your price for all users logged and not logged you comment the line of the condition in your code like this :

```
<?php // if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
   // your price tag here
<?php // endif; ?>
```

Comment: no this question is messed up the question is how to reverse or show price for users logged in or not

Comment: You have told that your theme is broken now because you had an error in the question posted

Comment: i backup up the theme before i made changes so i restored it to fix it but i would like to remove the hide price

Comment: you mean that you want to display the price for all without condition  and It will always be visible ?

Comment: Yes i would lie to display price for all

Comment: Look my update please